# SSIS File System Copy Task will not release file for editing

Tags: file, sql-server-2008, ssis, locking

I am using SSIS 2008 to make some .txt comma seperated files from SQL 2008 R2 queries. I have a template.txt document that holds a row of column headings, which I copy to a new location using a file system task. once that is done, I use the newly created file as a flat file destination to accept my SQL rows.

The problem I have is that the Data Flow task that should insert the SQL into the brand new destination file fails, reporting that the target file is locked by another process. Given that it is a brand new file, it seems to me that the only thing that could be locking it is the File System task that created the file itself - is there any way to stop this from happening or to release the lock?

The File System task and all others are inside a foreach loop.

I have tried inserting pauses into the flow, and using a script task to loop around until the file is unlocked; neither have worked. I think that the lock will have to be removed, or not created in the first place.

Everything I look up appears to work on the assumption that if you wait around long enough, the lock will go, but that has not been my experience here.

Any advice most welcome.

EDIT:

Replacing the File System Task with a Script Task that does the same thing has not solved the problem - it seems that the file that is newly created in the foreach loop stays locked by the package whether I try to edit it within the foreach loop or anywhere I have tried in the package.

I need some way to release the lock or stop it appearing on the file within the package to be able to update it - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try replacing the FST with a script task. 
Use C# & System.IO to copy the template.
The problem might be that the FST & The DFT are using the same File Connection object. At least if you get it to work with a script task it won't matter.
Also make sure you 100% are using the file you think you are - check for hardcoded expressions or configs being applied.

Comment: OK, so the problem appears not to be related to the FST - Using a script task containing `File.Copy(Template_File_Path, Target_File_Path);` causes the later DFT to fail with the same error. Is it to do with the ForEach loop, maybe..?

Comment: Just to clarify - unfortunately this approach yielded no result.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping each piece (FST and DFT) in its own sequence container.  I've been having file locking issues for about 2 years now, and I just resolved one that was preventing FTP of 3 files after data is extracted into them by wrapping the 3 data extracts in a sequence container.  The FTP tasks were already in a sequence container.

Comment: I will add to my answer that all online research I did regarding file locking during/after File System Tasks pointed to a problem with files stored on/accessed from shared drives.  None of that helped my situation.  Since I had started using Sequence Containers for a complex, multi-step ETL process, I decided to use them for each piece of a data extract followed by FTP process.  It worked.

Comment: I will throw in another tidbit gained through much research and troubleshooting.  The Microsoft Sysinternals toolset includes an executable called psfile.exe which supports advanced file management commands, including the ability to close all open file locks using a path and file name rather than a specific file ID.

Running the following command line will clear all open file locks on the specified file:
• C:\windows\psfile.exe "<drive letter>:\<path>\<filename.ext>" -c